# ios - ARKit 3D model material

Tags: swift, 3d, arkit

In ARKit the 3D model has two parts: the 3D object(scn, dae, obj,...) and material file (png). But is there anyway to have an 3D object with material embedded already (without set diffuse in code)?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Go into the Scene Editor by clicking on your 3d model in xcode. Make sure the Utilities tab is open (the right menu), then click on the Materials Inspector, the 5th option in the menu at the top of the Utilities tab (shown in screenshot). There you can choose the diffuse and set it as an image that is included in your normal Assets folder.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Thanks @Alan S. But you may have misunderstood me, my problem is I want my model has texture embedded already inside without choose the image in assets foler. Because my app is download the model from server but when downloaded it was miss the textures and the model is only grey color...

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is use Emcore3D (https://github.com/Things3D/Emcore3D) instead of SceneKit which means you 1. Dont need to reformat your 3d models ( simply pass the path to the obj/texture and material file) 2. Create the 3D object and render it on the render controller with 2 lines of code.

```
T3DRenderController *renderVC = [[T3DRenderController alloc] initWithSessionName:@"Session Name" withGraphicsAPIType:T3DGraphicsAPITypeOpenGL andLicenseKey:@"License Key"];

[self.view addSubview:renderVC.view];

T3DObject *newObject = [T3DObject initWithModelPathObject:newModelPath];

[renderVC addT3DObject:newObject];
```

PS - ARKit is integrated already in Emcore3D - simply call it to start AR tracking!

```
[renderVC startARKitWithConfiguration:T3DARConfigurationWorldTracking withCompletion:^{
   [renderVC addT3DObject:newObject];
}];
```

ps: Disclosure that I am part of the Emcore3D team

Comment: You've posted the same library to 5 different questions. If you're affiliated with the library, [you need to add disclosure](/help/promotion). Also, remember that excessive promotion isn't permitted either, and can result in your posts being considered spam.